# Error: Member not found: 'FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize'

Tags: flutter, firebase, push-notification

I am trying to implement notifications on flutter but I am getting a weird error:

I am calling the following function:

```
 initInfo() {
    var androidInitialize =
        const AndroidInitializationSettings("@mipmap/ic_launcher");
    var iOSInitialize = const IOSInitializationSettings();
    var initializationsSettings =
        InitializationSettings(android: androidInitialize, iOS: iOSInitialize);
    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationsSettings,
        onSelectNotification: (String? payload) async {
      try {
        if (payload != null && payload.isNotEmpty) ;
      } catch (e) {
        print(e);
      }
      return;
    });
  }
```

I am getting the following error:

Instance member 'initialize' can't be accessed using static access.

here is the error log:

```
: Error: Member not found: 'FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize'.
lib/navigator_view.dart:81
    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationsSettings,

                                    ^^^^^^^^^^
Restarted application in 271ms.
```

I am trying to follow this video: https://youtu.be/AUU6gbDni4Q?t=845

I was able to get pass the initial error by doing this::

```
initInfo() {
    var androidInitialize =
        const AndroidInitializationSettings("@mipmap/ic_launcher");
    var iOSInitialize = const IOSInitializationSettings();
    var initializationsSettings =
        InitializationSettings(android: androidInitialize, iOS: iOSInitialize);
    var fln = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();  // new code

    fln.initialize(initializationsSettings,
        onSelectNotification: (String? payload) async {
      try {
        if (payload != null && payload.isNotEmpty) ;
      } catch (e) {
        print(e);
      }
      return;
    });
  }
```

but now I am getting the following error:

```
/flutter (23250): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method initialize on channel dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications)
E/flutter (23250): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod
package:flutter/…/services/platform_channel.dart:294
E/flutter (23250): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (23250): #1      AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize
package:flutter_local_notifications/src/platform_flutter_local_notifications.dart:85
E/flutter (23250): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (23250):
```

should I not be doing this change?

Comment: Have you imported 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart' ? please share your entire main.dart file

Comment: hi, Juan, im currently facing the same issue. were able to fix it?